# What kind of tubing comes with a kitchen sink sprayer?

Tags: pvc, terminology

I need to replace the water supply tube on a concrete/masonry saw. It is rather too flexible and easily kinks and has developed a pinhole leak at the kink after only a few weeks of light use.

Now, we have an American Standard kitchen sink sprayer whose hose is a lot stiffer than the one that came on the saw. If it were the correct ID it would be perfect for the concrete saw.  I would like to shop for it in a different OD/ID, but I don't know the terminology for this kind of tubing. Is it PVC?  It has a diamond design on the tube. Is that functional reinforcement or merely decorative?

[image: American Standard sprayer hose]

Comment: You can buy various types of tubing by the foot at a good hardware store. This is a "shop around for your specific needs" kind of question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a functional reenforcement, and the product as a generic product is "mesh reinforced vinyl tubing" (or just "mesh reinforced tubing" which might catch a few in other plastics.)

[image: mesh reenforced tubing]

*[Image source](https://rubberandaccessories.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/reinforced-vinyl-tubing.jpg); no endorsement implied*

Order online, or possibly find it in a decent hardware store, if you have one of those. A hobby shop might also have some.

Another product without mesh that might work for you would be polyurethane fuel line, which is commonly available from motorsports suppliers, and typically has a thicker wall than most vinyl tubing.

Comment: My local Ace and Lowes has a selection of tubing sold by the foot.

Answer (score 9):

it's just called *reinforced braided vinyl tubing*. Your local plumbing, hardware, or marine supply shop probably sells it by the foot in various sizes.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's PVC tubing. Yes the braids are reinforcement. Without the reinforcement PVC tube is prone to bursting around 50 psi.

Get EPDM spray hose instead. Reinforced PVC tubing is prone to kinking and difficult to use in the cold. The EPDM hose is similar in price. Just don't drink from it.

Answer (score 4):

Automotive heater hose would possibly also work. It's black rubber instead of clear plastic but can easily be purchased in various diameters off a roll.  Being rubber it will be more abrasion resistant than plastic which may be a useful feature. Also, it's heat resistant (which is probably not needed).